# Select words from string according to array list

Tags: php

I want to select specific words from a sentence according to my array list

```
$sentence = "please take this words only to display in my browser";

$list = array ("display","browser","words","in");
```

I want the output just like " words display in browser"

please somebody help me with this one. THX

Comment: please elaborate. which language are you planning to use? is a a web app or a standalone program? where will the sentence and words come from. Basically WHY do you need this...

Comment: The question is tagged as PHP so I think he plans to use PHP, maybe I'm wrong :P

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this one liner would do it :

`echo join(" ", array_intersect($list, explode(" ",$sentence)));`

Use at your own risk :)

edit : yay, it does the job, just tested

Comment: Not bad, but I believe he wants it in the order they appear in the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with preg_match:

```
$sentence = "please take this words only to display in my browser";

$list = array ("display","browser","words","in");

preg_match_all('/\b'.implode('\b|\b', $list).'\b/i', $sentence, $matches) ;
print_r($matches);
```

You'll get the words in order

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => words
            [1] => display
            [2] => in
            [3] => browser
        )

)
```

But be careful with regular expressions performance if the text is not that simple.

Comment: Thanks man! I though the answer could be trashed for using regulars :-)

Comment: Regular expressions is a good solution I think. Gets the case insensitivity in there.  But actually, I'm wondering just now about the word "in": seems like in a broader application, it would find words like "find" and see the "in" in it.

Comment: Totally true, I've edit the solution to include the word boundary flag on the regular. Thanks!

Comment: You've got the solution. Regex to the rescue. :)

Comment: It'd great if you validate the answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any short version for this rather than checking word by word.

```
$words = explode(" ", $sentence);
$new_sentence_array = array();
foreach($words as $word) {
    if(in_array($word, $list)) {
        $new_sentence_array[] = $word;
    }
}

$new_sentece = implode(" ", $new_sentence_array);
echo $new_sentence;
```

Comment: I thought about this.  What about punctuation in sentences though?  I mean, I'm sure this could work in this example, but in a broader application I think it needs more.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could search the string for each value in the array and assign it to a new array with the `strpos` value as the key; that would give you a sortable array that you could then output in the order that the terms appear in the string. See below, or [example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/BV8WEL).

```
<?php
$sentence = "please take this words only to display in my browser";

$list = array ("display","browser","words","in");

$found = array();

foreach($list as $k => $v){
    $position = strpos(strtolower($sentence), strtolower($v));
    if($position){
    $found[$position] = $v; 
    }
}

ksort($found);
foreach($found as $v){
    echo $v.' ';    
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$narray=array();

foreach ($list as $value) {
    $status=stristr($sentence, $value);
    if ($status) {
        $narray[]=$value;
        }
}

echo @implode(" ",$narray);
```