# How to: compare array elements with a String

Tags: php, jquery

I have predefined an array:

```
$tags = array('PHP', 'Webdesign', 'Wordpress', 'Drupal', 'SQL');
```

Now I am inputting a value into a text area:

```
$text = 'Working With Wordpress Shortcodes and doing some NoSQL and SQL';
```

How can I compare the string value with the predefined array?

The desired result I want based on the above is 'Wordpress' and 'SQL'

Can I do it in PHP and JQuery?

Also, if it will contain a regular expression like

```
Working With Wordpress; Shortcodes: and doing some NoSQL and ""SQL
```

Then what to do?

Comment: Same question was asked 15 minutes before your question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10651491/select-words-from-string-according-to-array-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should split your string like so

```
$array = explode( ' ', $text );
```

Then compare like so

```
$result_array = array_intersect($tags, $array);
```

Now result_array will contain every value that is in both of the arrays :)

Comment: if it will contains with regular expression like === Working With Wordpress; Shortcodes: and doing some NoSQL and ""SQL == then what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Using [explode](http://php.net/explode) split the string to works, than for each word check [in_array](http://php.net/in_array)

```
$words = explode(' ', $text);
$result = array();
foreach ($words as $word) {
   if (in_array($word, $tags)) {
      $result[] = $word;
   }
}
```

Note: the comparision will be case-sensitivive

Comment: if it will contains with regular expression like === Working With Wordpress; Shortcodes: and doing some NoSQL and ""SQL == then what to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(explode(' ', $text) as $word) {
  if(in_array($word, $tags)) {
    // This word is in our tags array, do something.
  }
}
```

Comment: if it will contains with regular expression like === Working With Wordpress; Shortcodes: and doing some NoSQL and ""SQL == then what to do?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

i have found some solution and it works perfectly for me.
Firstly i am rearranged the string with a "," separated using

var valsp = $('#desc').val();
var results = valsp.split(/\W+/);

after this just using inArray() i am getting the desired result

Hope it will help to others